# Create a test for widget in yii

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii, phpunit, yii-extensions

I created a widget in Yii to display graphics using the http://www.highcharts.com/ library. My widget works pretty similar as `CGridView` widget from Yii.

I know that for visual elements I could have a functional test using Selenium, that I'm going to have. But, because the caracteristics of my widget (display a javascript result), I cannot find much problems on the visual elements.

How I can write a unit test to make sure the necessaries elements is displayed or loaded? I will give some examples below (using `CGridView` as example).

The oficial unit test for `CGridView` can be found here: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/tests/framework/zii/widgets/CGridViewTest.php

As you can see there, the test only make sure the scripts is registered, but, how about the logic behind? For example, this simple code:

```
public function renderTableBody()
{
    $data=$this->dataProvider->getData();
    $n=count($data);
    echo "<tbody>\n";
    echo '<tr><td colspan="'.count($this->columns).'" class="empty">';
    $this->renderEmptyText();
    echo "</td></tr>\n";
    echo "</tbody>\n";
}
```

There is no tests for that, is there some logical reason? How I can write a test for that? Maybe with `ob_start` and `ob_end_clean`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPUnit is used for server-side logic validation. You can't run JS code via PHP, so PHPUnit can not be used for testing logic behind the script. If you want to be sure that your script works correctly on client-side, you can use [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/) for that.